# Установка psycopg2

Tags: python

У меня M1 apple, не получается установить указанный пакет. Выходит ошибка(описана ниже). Пробывала:

```
!pip install psycopg2


!conda install -c anaconda psycopg2

# !source activate python2
# !conda install psycopg2
```

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - ^C
failed
```

Comment: Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: - ^C
failed

Comment: pip install psycopg2-binary  сработало так!

Answer (score 0):

!pip install psycopg2-binary
Сработало так.